# Paypal adaptive payment : payment chained / Error 550001 feespayer

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

How do i set feespayer in my live app?

What i want in the chained payment is for the secondary receiver to pay the paypal fee. But when ever i set the feespayer property when calling the API, i got 550001 error.

From what i read my live app doesn't have the permission to use this feature. How can i get this feature in? It was already requested when i submit the app.

Also, does anybody has any idea where do paypal/x.com developer should post their tickets/problems?

It seems like the x.com developer forums is a deserted place where no questions are being answered. The amount is worrying me that paypal will ignore mine as well.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure of two things.
1) Make sure that your PayPal account used as the API caller is **verified** (ie, you have a bank account linked to it) and is a premier account, or a business account.  Personal accounts won't work for this.

2) When you submitted your application, you had to check the field for Secondary Receiver paying fees. The problem is that even though you might have checked it, sometimes the form reviewers will miss it. To make sure that you have the permission you'll need to file a support ticket for it.

Merchant Technical Services is the place to do this: http://www.paypal.com/mts

Good luck!